# List Indexing from a file

Tags: python

Im trying to reach elements of two lists who both are within a list. And this last list (containing the other two lists) is in a file.

When I print the big list from my file, it looks like: ['[0,1],[2,3]'] and it is called rader.

```
rader = ['[0,1],[2,3]']
```

I'm trying to print the elements in the big list with the following command:
`print(rader[0][0])` which should give me the number 0 right? But when I do this I get an error: 'IndexError: list index out of range'.

I think that the problem is that when I open my txt.file with the list in it and read from it `(file = open('eddie.txt','r'))`, it interprets the whole thing as a String! Is that why I cant reach the elements in the list?

I want it like [[0,1],[2,3]] and not ['[0,1],[2,3]'] from the txt.file(I think?) 
How do I do this?

Here is my code:

```
from Tv_LABB2 import *


fil = open('edvin.txt','r', encoding = 'UTF-8')

rader = []

rad = fil.readline()

while rad !='':

    rader.append(rad)
    rad = fil.readline() 

fil.close()

fil = open('edvin.txt')

print(rader) (this is == ['[0,1],[2,3]'])

fil.close()



tv1 = TV('VardagsrumsTV',str(rader[0]),str(rader[1]))               

tv2 = TV('KöksTv',str(rader[2]),str(rader[3]))
```

As you can see Im importing some functions from another file, this code doesn´t run without it, but I think you understand my question!

Comment: Did you create this file originally? In which case, you could eliminate the problem at its source.

Comment: can you show us what the content of the file looks like? My guess is that a typical line looks like... `[0,1],[2,3]\n`

Comment: Yes, I did!  When I open my txt-file, it contains the following [[0,1],[2,3]] and not ['[0,1],[2,3]']. Otherwise I would erase the ' ', or what do you mean? - @roganjosh

Comment: In which case, you probably want something like the [pickle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) module to write your list to file, rather than a text file. Then this problem will go away.

Comment: I mean: did you _write_ the contents of this file or did someone else _write_ the contents? I'm not asking how it looks in a text editor.

Comment: Aha, now it occurs to me: did you manually write the contents of the file? In which case, my suggestion won't work. Pickle would only work if you programmatically wrote the file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make `rader` a list of lists not a list of a string

Use `rader = [[0,1],[2,3]]` not `rader = ['[0,1],[2,3]']`

Comment: The question is ambiguous but i think that was illustrating the output of `print` and not how the OP created the list.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert using `ast`:

```
>>> rader = ['[0,1],[2,3]'] 
>>> import ast
>>> r = list(ast.literal_eval(rader[0]))
>>> r
[[0, 1], [2, 3]]
>>> print r[0][0]
0
```

Answer (score 0):

Reading a file always produces byte or character strings.  If you want Python data structures, you have to make them.  Obviously, there are many tools already made to do this: the simplest (but [usually inadvisable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice)) is `eval`.  There is a safer variant called [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html).

Yet other choices involve changing the on-disk format.  You can just use whitespace to separate your values and use things like `str.split` to make lists, or you can (if your data came from another Python process) use `pickle`.

Also, a simplification: `rader=list(fil)` is all you need to read text lines.